# Configuration Item already exists [XL Deploy]

Tags: jenkins, cicd, xl-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a DAR on a server using XL Deploy, I get the following error message:

A Configuration Item with ID [CONFIGURATION_ITEM_ID] already exists.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to be a little bit more specific... you get the error before the deployment even starts?

If so, it may be because your application tries to deploy an artefact with the same name and on the same `container` as another, so as the same children. You'll have to have distinct name for your deployables across different applications, or deploy to different containers on you infrastructure.